# Apparently incorrect Fourier Series

Tags: bugs, series-expansion, fourier-analysis

While trying to compute Fourier Series, i find that It doesn't evaluate both positive and negative parts and hence apparently giving wrong answer. Below is the code that i tried:

```
 Clear[t, a, b, c, fn];
 fn[t_] := (a*Cos[t])/(b + c*(Cos[t])^2)^2;
 FourierSeries[fn[t], t, 3]
```

and it gives following output:

```
 (8 a E^(3 I t))/c^2
```

This can't be correct since i started with a real function. I then tried computing the co-efficient directly as below:

```
 1/(2 \[Pi]) Integrate[fn[t]*E^(3 I t), {t, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}]
 1/(2 \[Pi]) Integrate[fn[t]*E^(-3 I t), {t, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}]
```

that gives:

```
(4 a)/c^2
(4 a)/c^2
```

What is the reason for this difference? Could someone point me out as to how i can make Mathematica do the same for me?

Comment: Did you check the `FourierParameters` setting?

Comment: No, i wasn't aware of it!

Comment: Right, so check that the setting is compatible with whatever definition of the Fourier series you're using, and set accordingly. (This applies for all Fourier-related *Mathematica* functions.)

Comment: I can't see how i am going to use it in the code i've written above. I found something similar for Fourier transform, but not for the series.

Comment: Did you read the first and fourth bullet points under "Details and Options" for `FourierSeries[]`?

Comment: I've just gone through it and it seems that i want the default one i.e. (1,1), so there is no need to change it, right? Also, how is it possible that choice of this parameters makes the represention complex?

Comment: In that case, you can use `ComplexExpand[]` to convert complex exponentials into sines and cosines.

Comment: There is something off here.. `FourierCoefficient` would seem to be what you want, however it Yields `8 a/c^2` .  Also if I specify values for the constants the direct integration and the `FourierCoefficient` give completely different results.  Maybe someone who gets this should write up an answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think `FourierSeries` and `FourierCoefficient` are bugged here. To get the result you want, you could use `FourierCosSeries` or `FourierCosCoefficient`, or, if you're careful, `Integrate`.

We can simplify a little by pulling `a/b^2` out and defining `c -> b d`, to give

```
f = Cos[t]/(1 + d Cos[t]^2)^2;
```

Then we have

```
series = FourierCosSeries[f, t, 3, Assumptions -> d > 0]

(* Cos[t]/(1 + d)^(3/2) + 
  ((8 (-1 + Sqrt[1 + d]) + d (-12 - 3 d + 8 Sqrt[1 + d])) Cos[3 t])/(d^2 (1 + d)^(3/2)) *)
```

The result looks pretty good for `d = 1`:

```
Plot[Evaluate[{f, series} /. d -> 1], {t, -Pi, Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can also get the correct results for the Fourier coefficients using `Integrate` if you assume that `d > 0`:

```
Table[Integrate[f Exp[-k I t], {t, -Pi, Pi}, Assumptions -> d > 0]/(2 Pi), {k, -3, 3, 2}]

(* 
{
  (8 (-1 + Sqrt[1 + d]) + d (-12 - 3 d + 8 Sqrt[1 + d]))/(2 d^2 (1 + d)^(3/2)), 
  1/(2 (1 + d)^(3/2)), 
  1/(2 (1 + d)^(3/2)), 
  (8 (-1 + Sqrt[1 + d]) + d (-12 - 3 d + 8 Sqrt[1 + d]))/(2 d^2 (1 + d)^(3/2))
} 
*)
```

With no assumptions, however, you won't get useful results:

```
Table[Integrate[f Exp[-k I t], {t, -Pi, Pi}]/(2 Pi), {k, -3, 3, 2}]

(* {0, 0, 0, 0} *)
```

Now, what is going on with `FourierSeries`?

```
FourierSeries[f, t, 3]

(* (8 E^(3 I t))/d^2 *)
```

Not really sure, but note that it is giving the same result as for the function expanded around `d -> Infinity`:

```
Normal@Series[f, {d, Infinity, 0}]

(* Sec[t]^3/d^2 *)

FourierSeries[Sec[t]^3/d^2, t, 3]

(* (8 E^(3 I t))/d^2 *)
```

This is clearly wrong. It isn't even the correct series for `Sec[t]^3`, and adding assumptions on `d` doesn't help here. `FourierCoefficient` gives the same thing:

```
Table[FourierCoefficient[Sec[t]^3/d^2, t, k], {k, -3, 3, 2}]

(* {0, 0, 0, 8/d^2} *)
```

If we pull out the `d^2`, we get a slightly more reasonable result:

```
Table[FourierCoefficient[Sec[t]^3, t, k], {k, -3, 3, 2}]/d^2

(* {4/d^2, 0, 0, 4/d^2} *)
```

So it seems like there are definitely some problems going on here.

Comment: Nice! Consider sending a bug report, perhaps?